# Want to strip characters from a file (only shows in vi editor)

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file which shows ok when I do `cat test.txt`

```
cat test.txt
`variable "bigip_management_ip" {
  default = "54.210.108.205"
}`
```

however when I do vi its shows `default = "54.210.108.205^[[0m"`      I need to get rid of `^[[0m`
please help

Comment: Within vi have you tried `:set ft=unix` also check https://superuser.com/a/380778/284722

Comment: I was able to fix this issue after using  `perl -e 'use Term::ANSIColor; print color "white"; print "ABC\n"; print color "reset";' |  perl -pe 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' < test.txt > variables.tf # Removes special characters lik ^[[0m'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix issue using

```
perl -e 'use Term::ANSIColor; print color "white"; print "ABC\n"; print color "reset";' |  perl -pe 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' < test.txt > variables.tf # Removes special characters lik ^[[0m
```